# "An error occured while loading"- what's that?

Tags: bug, notifications

Today I can't open the inbox, or hot questions or notifications in any of the SE sites, I have tried it on Chrome, Firefox, Safari, but same error

[image]

[image]

Comment: still not able to open the inbox, and notifications, how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX request failed because of some reason. Maybe your connection was interrupted?

Check with firebug or developer tools. Normally failed requests are reported to the console.

Comment: You can't say with certainty that the bug is on the OP's side, a lot of times I've got similar error messages, SE's CDN was to blame.

Comment: @Yannis hmm, I think SE normally leaves a banner informing about such errors. Removed the line from answer =)

Comment: The CDN being unresponsive is not a SE error. Well, in a very broad sense it is, but it's not one of these things that the system can detect and raise a nice error about. It's another node between you and the site, all sorts of things can go wrong, and as any other server, it may face (momentarily or prolonged) bandwidth issues.

Comment: still not able to open the inbox, and notifications, how to fix this?