# An error occurred while loading, Please try again

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, achievements-dialog

When I click on the "achievements icon" on the nav-bar I get this:

[image]

Similar to : [“An error occured while loading”- what's that?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180605/325200)

But that is a very old post & the site has changed a lot since then, so is this a bug?

**Edit :**

***I am able to get the achievements drop-down now. But why didn't it work then?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recent achievements (as well as the recent inbox messages) are not loaded with the rest of the page contents. They are being loaded "on demand" only, when clicking the icon.

When clicking the icon, AJAX request is being sent from the browser to the server, asking it to serve the data, then the client process the result and show us the recent achievements.

When the internet connection is very slow, or broken, this AJAX request fails. The page itself loaded, probably slowly, but the AJAX request has a timeout, either set by SE (e.g. 20 seconds) or by the browser itself, hence after the timeout passed and still no response, it fails.

As Oded [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279066/152859) already, that's not something Stack Exchange can reproduce or fix, it's totally on your side, and can't really be fixed. Just wait until your connection will be normal again, and it will load fine.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the reply. I din't know it was an ajax call. I was thinking it will be loaded along with the page.

Comment: No problem, it's not trivial to know that. Loading it with the page means slower loading of the whole page, which isn't good. SE focus is on pages loading as fast as possible.

Comment: Thats good. SE loads pretty fast otherwise :)

Comment: @Ani also, you can browse directly to the raw data: http://meta.stackexchange.com/topbar/achievements which will show the the unparsed result. In case of bad connection, this might work while the AJAX fail.

Comment: Oh nice. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

> But why didn't it work then?

Who knows? Problem on your wifi? Network? ISP? A node between your and the Stack Exchange network? A network blip internally?

There are *a lot* of moving parts between you and the Stack Exchange servers and a temporary issue like this could be something gone wrong on any one of them.

Comment: True, but I had this question since I was able to use stack-overflow at the same time.

Comment: Also I din't know it was an ajax call. I had thought it would load along with the page.